# Не отображается контакт форм bootstrap

Tags: python, django

contact.html

```html
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

    <article class="media content-section">
      <h1>Обратная связь</h1>
    <form method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-info">Send</button>
    </form>
        </article>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import UserRegisterForm, UserUpdateForm, ProfileUpdateForm, ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views import View

def contact(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        mail = send_mail(form.cleaned_data['subject'], form.cleaned_data[
        'content'], 'smtp.gmail.com', ['@gmail.com'], fail_silently=False)
        if mail:
            messages.success(request, 'Письмо отправлено!')
            return redirect(contact)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ошибка отправки')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Ошибка регистрации')
else:
    form = ContactForm()
return render(request, 'contact.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .models import Profile

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
subject = forms.CharField(label='Тема', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
content = forms.CharField(label='Текст', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', "rows": 5}))
```

[image: форм]

Answer (score 0):

Используя ваш код повторил создание форм (всё работает)
[image: Форма созданная кодом]

Могу предположить что формы скрылись за другими элементами страницы

Проверьте их наличие через просмотр исходного кода в консоли разработчкика

> ```
> Google Chrome / Opera: Ctrl + Shift + J
> Mozilla Firefox: Ctrl + Shift + K
> ```

И если они там есть, редактируйте вёрстку

В ином случае ошибка кроется за пределами оставленного вами кода.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcFRG.jpg (что делать как исправить)